# How can I store the aggregated result of a soql count in a List

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm trying to count the number of related accounts a contact has.
This number should be stored in a custom field on "Contact" and should be updated every time relation is added or deleted, thus via trigger code.
In order to count the number of current relations I want to store the result of following query on a List that I want to loop afterwards to update the contact record(s):

```
List<AccountContactRelation> acr = new List<AccountContactRelation>([SELECT ContactId, Count(Id) FROM AccountContactRelation WHERE ContactId IN :contactIds AND Active__c = true GROUP by ContactId]);
```

However, this throws an error:

> "System.ListException: Row with null Id at index: 0"

How can I build this List for further processing?

Kind regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

Generally speaking running SOQL in Apex produces a value that is materialized into a single `SObject` class, or a `List<SObject>` (either a generic SObject, or the exact SObject type to match the `FROM` clause type). This is precisely what you're trying to do.

However when running aggregate SOQL in Apex, there are some different [rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm).

First off, if the aggregation results in a single simple number value, you may get a return type of `Integer`.

```
Integer myAggregate = [SELECT Count() FROM Account WHERE Type = 'Prospect']; 
System.debug(myAggregate);  //output: 36
```

However with what you're doing, there is a special generic type for aggregate values called `AggregateResult`. An `AggregateResult` instance essentially works like a map where each field is accessed by its key and is retrieved using the `get('fieldName')` accessor. Your query will return this in a `List`. Here's one possible flow how you would use it to create a list of contacts that you want to update.

```
List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>(); 

List<AggregateResult> resultList = [SELECT ContactId, Count(Id) relationCount
                               FROM AccountContactRelation 
                               WHERE ContactId IN :contactIds 
                                 AND Active__c = true GROUP by ContactId];

for (AggregateResult ar: resultList) {
  //assign to contacts here.
  Contact contactToUpdate = new Contact(); 
  contactToUpdate.Id = (Id) ar.get('ContactId'); 
  contactToUpdate.Custom_Count_Field__c = (Integer) ar.get('relationCount');

  contactsToUpdate.add(contactToUpdate); 
} 

// always perform DML outside of loops in Apex
update contactsToUpdate; //you may want to use Database.update()
```

A couple of things to note.

- You don't need to invoke an `SObject` or `List` constructor when executing inline SOQL. It is implicit.
- In the aggregate query, note the use of the alias. While aliases are mostly irrelevant in SOQL (in my opinion) here they are essential, as otherwise a generic keys get assigned for all aggregate values called `expr0`, `expr1`, etc.... Don't do that to yourself.
- The fields of `AggregateResult` are all generically typed as `Object`. You'll need to cast them to match the underlying SObject field type. In my case I've assumed your custom field is defined as a Number field.